# Different applications and Threadpool threads (or not)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, task, threadpool

I tested different projects with this simple code :  *( 2010 ,4.5.1)*

```
bool a, b;
new Thread(() => { a = Thread.CurrentThread.IsThreadPoolThread; }).Start();
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { b = Thread.CurrentThread.IsThreadPoolThread; });
```

I wanted to see which projects uses threadpool thread and which doesn't : *( as a default(!) invocation without LongOperation switch)*

So :

**WPF**
[image]

— Doesn't use threadpool threads.

**Console**
[image]

— Doesn't use threadpool threads.

**Winform**
[image]

— Doesn't use threadpool threads.

**Asp.net**

[image]

— **Does** use for `Task`

It's actually  the last place I'd think about - that asp.net uses threadpool thread for task. ( each threadpool thread is important for serving other requests)

**Question**

Why does *Only* asp.net uses threadpool thread when creating/running new task ? ( Also , with the fact that Tp threads are precious resource)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They all use threadpool threads, you are not waiting long enough for the code to run. You need to do a `.Join()` on your thread version and a `.Wait()` on the task version to wait for the code to complete before you check the result of `a` and `b`.

```
bool a, b;
new Thread(() => { a = Thread.CurrentThread.IsThreadPoolThread; }).Start().Join();
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { b = Thread.CurrentThread.IsThreadPoolThread; }).Wait();
```

Comment: You're right, Now I feel really dumb :-) ( well at least I was corrected)

Comment: (all yields same results :-))

Comment: Weird , But if I trace line by line it does change the right  values - while putting a breakpoint like I did - does not show the changes....

Comment: BTW - `new Thread` is not using threadpool thread. https://i.imgur.com/KyIFBwi.jpg and [this](https://i.imgur.com/QJTUvZX.jpg)